# C unable to recognise function pointer types as the same

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, function-pointers, pintos

In a recent project, I've been struggling to fix this syntax error for the last hour or so; gcc complains about a type mismatch between what it says are two objects of identical type:

```
../../devices/timer.c: In function ‘timer_interrupt’:
../../devices/timer.c:181:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘thread_foreach’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  181 |   thread_foreach (timer_check, NULL);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   void (*)(struct thread *, void *)
In file included from ../../devices/timer.c:9:
../../threads/thread.h:134:42: note: expected ‘void (*)(struct thread *, void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(struct thread *, void *)’
  134 | void thread_foreach (thread_action_func *func, void *aux);
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
../../devices/timer.c: At top level:
../../devices/timer.c:185:1: error: conflicting types for ‘timer_check’
  185 | timer_check (struct thread *thread, void *aux) {
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../devices/timer.c:1:
../../devices/timer.h:29:6: note: previous declaration of ‘timer_check’ was here
   29 | void timer_check(struct thread *thread, void *aux);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've played around with things like adding / removing reference or dereference operators, changing some of the signatures for the functions involved to make them more similar to examples I've seen online.

For example, I have tried changing the signature of `thread_action_func` from `typedef void thread_action_func` to `typedef void (*thread_action_func)`, and changing the usage of the type in function arguments from `thread_action_func *` to `thread_action_func`, but it either complains about the type passed no longer being a function or function pointer, or throws the same error about identical types being mismatched.

I have also tried adding an address-of in front of where the function `thread_foreach` calls `timer_check` as an argument, like `thread_foreach(&timer_check,...)`, but the error remained the same as initially.

The relevant functions / prototypes / typedefs are:

thread.h:

```
struct thread
  {
    ...
    int64_t block_ticks;
    ...
  };

typedef void thread_action_func (struct thread *t, void *aux);
void thread_foreach (thread_action_func *func, void *aux);
```

thread.c:

```
void
thread_foreach (thread_action_func *func, void *aux)
{
  struct list_elem *e;

  ASSERT (intr_get_level () == INTR_OFF);

  for (e = list_begin (&all_list); e != list_end (&all_list);
       e = list_next (e))
    {
      struct thread *t = list_entry (e, struct thread, allelem);
      func (t, aux);
    }
}
```

timer.h:

```
void timer_check(struct thread *thread, void *aux);
```

timer.c:

```
void
timer_sleep (int64_t ticks) 
{
  int64_t start = timer_ticks ();

  ASSERT (intr_get_level () == INTR_ON);

  struct thread *cur = thread_current();
  cur->block_ticks = ticks;
  enum intr_level old_level = intr_disable ();
  thread_block();

  intr_set_level (old_level);
  thread_yield();
}

static void
timer_interrupt (struct intr_frame *args UNUSED)
{
  ticks++;
  thread_tick ();
  thread_foreach (timer_check, NULL);
}

void 
timer_check (struct thread *thread, void *aux) {
  if (thread->status == THREAD_BLOCKED) {
    thread->block_ticks--;
    if (thread->block_ticks <= 0) {
      thread_unblock(thread);
    }
  }
}
```

All of the results I found by searching for this kind of problem were only similar in one aspect or the other, not close enough to be useful e.g. showing what the example of a function pointer is or an error with pointers to integers or characters.

I would guess this is some obvious syntax mistake which I was too frustrated to notice, but I can't really see clearly what may be causing the issue at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you redefine a `struct` tag in a different scope.

You have not provided a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we cannot definitively identify where the error is, but it can be that this code in `timer.h`:

```
void timer_check(struct thread *thread, void *aux);
```

declares `struct thread` with function prototype scope. This defines a `struct` type only for the duration of the function declaration, which is generally useless.

Then, in `timer.c`, presumably you include some header that declares `thread_unblock`, and this header is included after `timer.h` is included (if it is). That header declares its own `struct thread` and uses it in the declaration of `thread_unblock`.

Since the function `timer_check` takes a parameter of a type that is different from the one used in `thread_unblock`, the compiler reports they have incompatible types, even though they have the same name (coming from different scopes).

To fix that, `timer.h` should include the header that declares `struct thread` before it declares `timer_check`. Then the parameter declaration `struct thread *thread` will refer to the already visible structure type instead of defining a new one.

For illustration, here is code that will reproduce the error:

```
// struct thread; // Uncommenting this line will elimninate the error.

void foo(struct thread *);
void bar(void (*)(struct thread *));
void baz(void)
{
    bar(&foo);
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response and not providing the Minimal Reproducible Example. This seems to have worked so I think you correctly found the error at play - thank you.